# Broadband RF Signal Generator

Tags: rf, function-generator

I am in the process of designing an RF signal generator, as many of my other projects require analysis up to several GHz. My hope was to receive some verification regarding the intended design. Nothing too detailed at this point, primarily just theory. Ideally, the design will achieve the "optimal requirements" listed in the table below, however, I would still be satisfied with the minimal requirements for a first design.

[image]

**Design Approach**

Referencing [this](http://www.analog.com/en/analog-dialogue/articles/reinvent-the-signal-generator.html) article from Analog Devices, a signal generator design was presented, but no where near the frequency I require. Instead of using the AD9834C as they list (schematic below), I intend to use the [AD9102](http://www.analog.com/media/en/technical-documentation/data-sheets/AD9102.pdf) DAC/DDS. This will provide a frequency up to 180 MHz, then, utilizing a wideband synthesizer and mixer, I intend to upconvert the signal. The [LMX2592](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/lmx2592.pdf) has a frequency range of 20 MHz to 9.8 GHz, and the VGA in the schematic below is limited to 18 MHz, so theoretically my maximum frequency will be:

$$f_{o_{max}} = 9800 + 18 = 9.818 \text{ GHz}$$

This is close enough, but I could also choose a higher frequency synthesizer or wider bandwidth VGA. It should also be noted that some variable bandpass filtering will be required on the output.

[image: Analog Devices Signal Generator]

**Primary Concern**

In order to achieve 40 Vpp output at higher frequencies, given a 50 ohm load, that means the output power must be 36 dBm:

$$P_O = 10\cdot \log_{10}\left(\frac{40 / 2\sqrt{2}}{50} \cdot 1\times 10^3\right) = 36 \text{ dBm}$$

The reference design provided by Analog Devices demonstrates P1dB at 36 dBm, so this should theoretically be possible to achieve that output power when upconverted - although the mixer will have a conversion loss (~6 dB). This suggests an output power of +30 dBm at higher frequencies, thus yielding 20 Vpp output. Again, although this is not optimal, I would still be satisfied given the frequency range trade-off.

The board will most likely be etched or purchased from Oshpark, including proper transmission lines (coplanar waveguide with ground). I'm worried that given the wide bandwidth, multiple transmission lines and RF switches would be necessary for different regions of the band (e.g. 0 to 1 GHz, 1 to 5 GHz, 5 GHz to 10 GHz) to avoid significant losses?

**Final Thoughts**

I primarily wanted to check my thought process against some of you who are more experienced! Any thoughts would be appreciated. It is quite possible this frequency range and output voltage is a castle in the sky, as they say?

Comment: The +30 dBm output spec is going to make this very challenging. I don't see any product that does this from Keysight or R+S (not that R+S makes it easy to search their products). The usual way to do this is probably to get a lower power synthesizer and add a power amp (tuned to the band for the particular test being done) to the front of it.

Comment: @ThePhoton Would a power amp be necessary? My thought was to provide as much gain prior to upconversion, hence using the schematic reference above, which outputs up to 36 dBm. As long as the synthesizer can meet the LO drive power of the mixer (0 - 5 dBm), and the mixer has a conversion loss of 6 dB, +30 dBm output power should be possible? The frequency response of the mixer would have to be linear across the entire range, of course.

Comment: @ThePhoton Also, I would like to have the AD9102 chip since arbitrary waveforms is possible as opposed to just sine waves.

Comment: What mixer did you have in mind?

Comment: Fair point! Not many mixers exist that can support this power level or frequency range I now see... The LTC5510 supports up to 6 GHz, but P1dB is 11 dBm so a power amplifier will be needed.

Comment: That's a very challenging design, even in the minimum requirements. I'm not sure that if the goal isn't to design something *yourself*, buying a ready, commercial off-the-shelf software defined radio, and a set of amplifiers for the different bands, won't be much easier and probably also cheaper...

Comment: [This](http://www.markimicrowave.com/Assets/datasheets/T3-10.pdf) gets you closer, but still not quite there I don't think (but I am not really an RF guy).

Comment: What is the goal for the level of signals at the output that are not at the desired frequency? For example, it looks like there would be just as much 9.782 Ghz as there is 9.818 GHz at the output, since the mixer produces both upper and lower products equally.

Comment: 40 v p-p at 10 GHz is pie in the sky for a home spun design with 10,000 volts per micro second as the approximate rise and fall time.

Comment: @TomAnderson I was thinking of having an adjustable bandpass filter, but I think it would get too complicated.

Comment: @Andyaka Thank you, I wanted to see if this was feasible or not.